# Cast object to generic delegate using system.type

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I wish to cast an object into a generic delegate with system.type information so that I can invoke the delegate. The object is guaranteed to be convertible to the delegate.

Delegate example:

```
public delegate void CallbackFn<T>(InterfacedDataType<T> data) where T : InterfaceBase;
```

And the struct holding the callback object and type information:

```
public struct CallbackFnWrapper
{
    public System.Type T;
    public object delegateObject;

    public void Invoke(InterfaceBase data) 
    {
        ((CallbackFn<T>)(delegateObject)).Invoke((T)data); //Does not compile
    }
}
```

The line `((CallbackFn<T>)(delegateObject)).Invoke((T)data);` does not compile for obvious reasons, however I fail to grasp the syntax required to do 2 things:

1. Cast `delegateObject` to `CallbackFn<T>`
2. Cast `InterfaceBase data` to `InterfacedDataType<T>`

**Edit**:

The invoke function has to be kept with the current signature:

```
public void Invoke(InterfaceBase data)
```

This function is used in a scope where there is no type information available so I cant template that function.

Example Function where invoke is used:

```
List<CallbackFnWraper> fnlist;
foreach(var fn in fnlist) fn.Invoke(somedata);
```

**Edit 2:**

I made a small program that is "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable" so if anyone wants to give it a shot:

```
public class DataTypeBase { }

public class DataTypeDerivedA : DataTypeBase
{
    public int i = 0;
}

public class DataTypeDerivedB : DataTypeBase
{
    public char c = ' ';
}

public class RunEnvironment
{
    public void Run()
    {
        DataTypeDerivedA a = new DataTypeDerivedA();
        a.i = 555;
        DataTypeDerivedB b = new DataTypeDerivedB();
        b.c = '@';
        Wrapper w1 = MakeWrapper<DataTypeDerivedA>(Test1);
        Wrapper w2 = MakeWrapper<DataTypeDerivedB>(Test2);

        w1.Invoke(a);
        w2.Invoke(b);
    }

    public Wrapper MakeWrapper<T>(CallbackFn<T> fn) where T : DataTypeBase
    {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.T = typeof(T);
        w.delegateObject = fn;
        return w;
    }

    public void Test1(DataTypeDerivedA data)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(data.i);
    }

    public void Test2(DataTypeDerivedB data)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(data.c);
    }
}

public delegate void CallbackFn<T>(T data) where T : DataTypeBase;
public struct Wrapper
{
    public System.Type T;
    public object delegateObject;

    public void Invoke(DataTypeBase data)
    { 
        ((CallbackFn<T>)(delegateObject)).Invoke((T)(data)); //Won't compile
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunEnvironment r = new RunEnvironment();
        r.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics are great when you know the type at compile time. Not so much when you dont know the type until runtime. There are reflection workarounds but they're ugly and slow. Best advice: do this without generics.

Comment: Im using the struct as a type-erasure-ish way to remove the type information. So that I can have a container of these type erased delegates.

Comment: @Jamiec that is what I suspected and I am looking for insight on how to achieve this with or without reflection.

Comment: @Jamiec so how do I go about it using reflection?

Comment: Hard to tell with the code you've shown - provide a [mcve] and i'll give it a go

Comment: `((Delegate)(delegateObject)).DynamicInvoke(data);` would compile and probably work, but I doubt it's a good solution for what you are trying to achieve and am not sure if it even works for all your use cases.

Comment: @RenéVogt it would probably work if not for the generic aspect of the delegate and the scope of where this cast is taking place where there isn't any type information about the delegate.

Comment: @Jamiec I made a small sample showcasing the compile error. The expected output is to print out "555" and "@". Do I edit my question to add in the sample I made? Or should I post a new question with the code sample I made?

Comment: @Jamiec I'm not following your confusion. I want to cast the object to a delegate which takes in a single argument which implements an interface. 
The 'data' has to be casted as well because its passed through its interface.

Comment: @Jamiec woops! Yes its meant to be 'delegateObject'

Comment: Note that I updated my answer after you accepted it - its easier still then my first attempt

Comment: @RenéVogt Ironically, that was the solution in the end - I wonder what scenarios you think this wouldnt cover?

Comment: @Jamiec I simply don't know _well enough_ what `DynamicInvoke` does (yes I know `dynamic`, DLR and dynamic binding). I wasn't sure if this works for all kind of types for `T`, and if I don't know _exactly_ that this is a good solution, I don't post it as an answer. Now thinking about it, the `Delegate` has all information about the target object and method to invoke, so it seems to be the solution to OP's immediate problem... still unsure if this isn't an xy-problem and there is an overall better solution for what OP actually wants to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this turned out to be pretty simple. You simply needed to cast your `delegateObject` to a `Delegate` type and call `DynamicInvoke`.

```
public struct Wrapper
{
    public System.Type T;
    public object delegateObject;

    public void Invoke(DataTypeBase data)
    { 
       ((Delegate)delegateObject).DynamicInvoke(data); //Will compile
    }
}
```

Working example: http://rextester.com/CQG34502